# How to create a Javascript PURE animation that counts from zero to the Element contained in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a script that counts from ZERO to a number that will be fed via PHP, for example my HTML is

```
<h1 class = "myClass"> 500 </h1>
<h1 class = "myClass"> 424 </h1>
<h1 class = "myClass"> 424 </h1>
```

I would like to retrieve the values ​​of elements that contain a specific class and count from Zero to themselves.

But I would like it done in Javascript, I've seen some Jquery Plugins But I would like to do the same thing in javascript, just like this example: https://codepen.io/shivasurya/pen/FatiB

Detail, it would be interesting for the count to end at the same time for small values ​​and larger values.

I already tried something like:

```
function ng_count_number_animation (element) {
    let select = window.document.querySelectorAll (element);
    let start = 0;

    let i;

    for (i = 0; i <select.length; i ++) {
        for (let y = 0; y <= Number (select [i] .innerHTML); y ++) {
            select [i] .innerHTML = y;
        }
    }
}

ng_count_number_animation (". ng_count_number");
```

But it never works, I also used the Javascript setinterval to interval the count but it also doesn't work, always the result is ZERO in all classes.

Comment: No, you can't select multiple elements and animate them all at once without having to call the function multiple times.

Comment: _“it would be interesting for the count to end at the same time for small values ​​and larger values”_ - if you want them to start and have them end at the same time, then you will of course have to either modify the interval or the increment step accordingly …

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using requestAnimationFrame(), to execute a function as often as possible. My code is not the most efficient,  but I think it should be easy enough to understand :

```js
//retrieve all counters from body
let counters = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');

//retrieve all counter value
let vals = Array.from(counters).map(x => Number(x.innerHTML));

//convert counters element collection to an array
counters = Array.from(counters);

//loop through all counters
counters.forEach(el => {
  //set counter to 0
  el.innerHTML = '0';
  //set 'internal' counter to 0 -> obviously this isn't super efficient
  //could be faster if you used an array instead
  el.counter = 0;
});

//execute this function as often as possible using requestAnimationFrame()
let update = () => {
  //loop through all counters
  counters.forEach((el, i) => {
    //add one to 'internal counter'
    el.counter += 1;
    //update counter display value min(max, currentVal + 1)
    el.innerHTML = Math.min(vals[i], el.counter);
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
```

```html
<h1 class = "myClass"> 500 </h1>
<h1 class = "myClass"> 424 </h1>
<h1 class = "myClass"> 424 </h1>
```

Comment: But is there a way for the count to stop at the same time regardless of the number of digits ??? for example: 100, 1000, 100000, does the animation stop at the same time?

Comment: you could do that by either using a different increment value, or a a different speed